# Unknown Column name in field list- MySQL

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-error-1054

This seems to me like it is really a simple fix but I can't figure it out.  Here is the question that I'm working on:

4. Create a view named order_item_products that returns columns from the Orders, Order_Items, and Products tables.
   This view should return these columns from the Orders table: order_id, order_date, tax_amount, and ship_date.
   This view should return these columns from the Order_Items table: item_price, discount_amount, final_price (the discount amount subtracted from the item price), quantity, and item_total (the calculated total for the item).
   This view should return the product_name column from the Products table

And here is my code:

```
    CREATE VIEW order_item_products AS
     SELECT o.order_id, o.order_date, o.tax_amount, o.ship_date,
                 oi.item_price, oi.discount_amount,  oi.quantity, 
             (oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) AS actual_price,
    (actual_price * oi.quantity) AS final_price,
              p.product_name
FROM orders o 
    JOIN order_items oi on o.order_id = oi.order_id
    JOIN products p ON p.product_id = oi.product_ID;
```

I am getting the error message Unknown column "actual_price" in field list.  What am I doing wrong?  It will not calculate the final price.  I removed the final price statement and my query executed, so it is allowing it to become a column.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can't use an alias at the same time you're defining it. so `(actual_price * oi_quantity)` would have to be `((oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * oi.quantity)`

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use alias before it actually exists. I think this should work:

```
CREATE VIEW order_item_products AS
    SELECT
        o.order_id,
        o.order_date,
        o.tax_amount,
        o.ship_date,
        oi.item_price,
        oi.discount_amount,
        oi.quantity, 
        (oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) AS actual_price,
        ((oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * oi.quantity) AS final_price,
        p.product_name
    FROM orders AS o 
    JOIN order_items AS oi
        ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
    JOIN products AS p
        ON p.product_id = oi.product_ID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

My version seems working:

```
CREATE or REPLACE view order_item_product
AS SELECT o.order_id,o.order_date,o.tax_amount,o.ship_date,
oi.item_price,oi.discount_amount,oi.item_price-oi.discount_amount AS final_price,oi.quantity,COUNT(oi.item_id) AS item_total,
p.product_name
FROM orders o,orderitems oi,product p
WHERE o.order_id=oi.order_id
AND p. product_id=oi. product_id;
```